# Stuck - everything possibilities - index.php can not remove on url from server in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I stuck for this..

index.php can not remove on url from server

I try in localhost working well

this my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I was try everything possibilities (htaccess) to solve this ..

May you give me advice or solution to fix this .

Thank you so much ..

Comment: change `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';` and try

Comment: What URL do you try? What do you expect to happen? And what does happen instead?

Comment: Is location of CI application in root directory of web server or in some subdirectory?

Comment: url work : alpha.com/index.php/login .. url can't work : alpha.com/login .. i want to remove index.php @OlafDietsche

Comment: directory in server =====>    / => root => var => www => alpha @Tpojka

Comment: In case you are using default apache configuration, in `.htaccess` file, at begining just after `RewriteEngine on` line (meaning in next line) put `RewriteBase /alpha/`. You can also check [this code](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/) that I found very useful.

Comment: can not working :( @Tpojka i was change rewritebase into /alpha/ and /  but can not working

Comment: Try code from link I provided. Read it carefully and make needed changes accordingly.

Comment: wait .. i want to ask .. apache configuration how ? must change or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) create .htaccess file in the root directory and add this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

2.) Make following changes in your config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

If `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';` doesn't help, try changing it to:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING'; OR,
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; OR,
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'ORIG_PATH_INFO';
```

3.) Make following edits in your httpd.conf file inside `apache` directory

`AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All` and, `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` to `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Comment: part 1 and 2 i try and can't working .. part  3 not yet.. because im on server .. i try it first ..

Comment: but when in local i try to edit this -> AllowOverride none to AllowOverride All and AllowOverride All to AllowOverride none can working well

Comment: but i want to try in server first

Comment: Try this in the .htacess file:

    `RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /your_application/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|css|captcha|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: the third execuse is success

Answer (score 1):

Remove index url in config.php.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and htaccess as follow

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Hope it will solve your issue. If not let me know

Comment: make sure you have enabled rewrite module in your Apache Module.

Answer (score 1):

1) create .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

2) Edit config/config.php  file

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname';

 $config['index_page'] = '';         // remove index.php
```